# Select input type=text value as column name

Tags: javascript, php, html

php

```
  $searchby =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['searchby']);
  $searchx =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['searchx']);
  $order=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['order']);

  $fetchquery9 = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE '$searchby' = '$searchx' ORDER BY '$order'"; //sql query
  $fetch9 = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchquery9);
```

ajax

```
  function sortdata(){
  var searchby = $('#searchby').val();
  var searchx = $('#searchx').val();
  var order = $('#order').val();


  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "getdatasort.php?searchby="+searchby+"&searchx="+searchx+"&order="+order
}).done(function( data ) {
  $('#viewdata').html('');
  $('#viewdata').html(data);
 });
 }//passing value using ajax
```

html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="searchby" name="searchby"     placeholder="searchby" onChange="sortdata();">
<option value="reservationno">Reservation No.</option>
<option value="name">Full Name</option>
<option value="number">Contact Number</option>
<option value="email">Email</option>
<option value="course_reservation">Course</option>
<option value="class_code_reservation">Class Code</option>
<option value="startdate">Start Date</option>
<option value="enddate">End Date</option>
<option value="desired_date">Desired Date</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchx" name="searchx"             placeholder="Searh here" onChange="sortdata();">
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="order" name="order">
<option value="ASC">ascending</option>
<option value="DSC">descending</option>
</select>
</div>
```

i just wanna know how to set a input type=text value as column name in sql query in php. Having 3 input text where a user can view sql data depending on the value of text value. first input contains sql column second input search item and third input the order (asc or desc)

Comment: This `ORDER BY '$order'` is invalid. You need a column name/expression. That value should be in backticks.

Comment: yah my mistake..thank you chris85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to remove the quotes

```
$fetchquery9 = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE $searchby = '$searchx' ORDER BY $order"; //sql query
```